# Same data structure is imported twice and cannot access underlying data

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get line number of out of `SourcePos` using `sourceline`
So I imported `Text.Parsec.Pos(SourcePos,sourceLine)`.
However, another module (`Language.ECMAScript3.Syntax`) which creates `SourcePos`, exports as its own type but it does not export `sourceLine`.

That did not help. I get this error: src\Main.hs:62:53:

> ```
> Couldn't match type `Text.Parsec.Pos.SourcePos'
>               with `Language.ECMAScript3.Syntax.SourcePos'
> Expected type: JavaScript Language.ECMAScript3.Syntax.SourcePos
>                -> [Char]
>   Actual type: JavaScript Text.Parsec.Pos.SourcePos -> [Char]    ....
> ```

```
list (one:rest) = case one of
      (VarDeclStmt _ [VarDecl _ (Id ln a) _]) -> "\nvar "++  (show  (sourceLine (ln)) )  ++ (show a)++ list rest
      otherwise -> list rest
```

The larger context:

```
 lookAtJsModule src label func =
     case parseFromString src of
        Left err -> "Can't parse a test-case: " ++
                                    "\nThe error was " ++ (show err)
        Right js -> label ++ (func js)


    list0 tree = case tree of
        (Script a b)   -> list b

    --list :: [Language.ECMAScript3.Syntax.Statement a] -> String

    list (one:rest) = case one of
          (VarDeclStmt _ [VarDecl _ (Id (ln ) a) _]) -> "\nvar "++  (show  ((ln  )) )  ++ (show a)++ list rest
          otherwise -> list rest

    list[] = ""


    listSpecificModule src = lookAtJsModule src "list:" list0

listVars _ = do
  content <- getContents
```

putStrLn (listSpecificModule content) 0

Note it is the same "thing". Is there way, e.g. cast to solve this?

Comment: Can you show the code that's giving you the error?

Comment: We're probably going to need more code than that.  Can you post a minimal *complete* example that gives the error, and the full error too.

Comment: `Language.ECMAScript3.Syntax` does not export `SourcePos` field accessors,   but for printing purposes you can just `(show ln)` instead of `(show  (sourceLine (ln)))`.

Comment: That is what I wrote in the introduction. I know that works.. what if I woule like to have line number only? How do I use field accessors when there are not exported?

Comment: Ah, `Language.ECMAScript3.Syntax` just re-exports `SourcePos` from `Text.Parsec.Pos`. In this case `(show  (sourceLine (ln)))` should typecheck as long as both `language-ecmascript` and your package have depend on the _same_ version of `parsec`.

Comment: You mean could not match happens because parsec versions are not the same?

Comment: Yes. For example `language-ecmascript` have been built with `parsec-3.1.1` and re-exports `parsec-3.1.1:Text.Parsec.Pos.SourcePos` but your package imports from `parsec-3.1.2`. In this case `((sourceLine :: parsec-3.1.2:SourcePos -> Int) (ln :: parsec-3.1.1:SourcePos))` will not typecheck because `parsec-3.1.1:Text.Parsec.Pos.SourcePos` and `parsec-3.1.2:Text.Parsec.Pos.SourcePos` are different datatypes.

Comment: HOw can I see what version is used by language-ecmascript?

Comment: It did not seem to help what you recommended

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use qualified imports to fix this problem. For example:

```
import qualified Text.Parsec.Pos as PP
import qualified Language.ECMAScript3.Syntax as ES
```

Then you can refer functions or type/value constructors from these modules like this:

```
-- function from Text.Parsec.Pos
PP.function

-- function from Language.ECMAScript3.Syntax
ES.function
```